# codeigniter route is showing?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

my route 
$routes->get('/login', 'Home::index');

it shows 
wamp details 
home route 
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
 is working fine but 
when i put login in it it showsall wamp details

Answer (score 0):

in codeginiter route defined as

```php
$route['login'] = 'Home/index';
```

refrence

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html